# Executing external libraries for cmake(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cmake, ninja

I am trying to build a project but its gradle is not working properly. First it was giving me error that NDK should be there so i download ndk from sdk manager but still it is giving me error and i m not able to find how can i resolve it?

Please look at my error and tell me what should i do for gradle build?

```
executing external native build for cmake C:\Users\Geet\Downloads\woocommercesourcecode\codecanyon-25092266-woobox-native-android-app-for-woocommerce\MainFile_Android_SourceCode\Android App source code\woobox_droid\app\CMakeLists.txt
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  executing external native build for cmake C:\Users\Geet\Downloads\woocommercesourcecode\codecanyon-25092266-woobox-native-android-app-for-woocommerce\MainFile_Android_SourceCode\Android App source code\woobox_droid\app\CMakeLists.txt
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: executing external native build for cmake C:\Users\Geet\Downloads\woocommercesourcecode\codecanyon-25092266-woobox-native-android-app-for-woocommerce\MainFile_Android_SourceCode\Android App source code\woobox_droid\app\CMakeLists.txt